Terraform Latest: Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: *** : context deadline exceeded
I am using the latest version of terraform and the azurerm provider in my code is "~>3.0".
I am getting Error: retrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: *** : context deadline exceeded.
My code is provided below, please help me to resolve this error.
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa-int" {
  name                             = .......
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                         = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier                     = "Standard"
  account_replication_type         = "LRS"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public  = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
  min_tls_version                  = "TLS1_2"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "1h"
    update = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }  
  blob_properties {
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }

  }
  queue_properties {
    logging {
      delete                = true
      read                  = true
      write                 = true
      version               = "1.0"
      retention_policy_days = 10
    }
    hour_metrics {
      enabled               = true
      include_apis          = true
      retention_policy_days = 10
      version               = "1.0"

    }
    minute_metrics {
      enabled               = true
      include_apis          = true
      retention_policy_days = 10
      version               = "1.0"


    }

  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  count                 = length(var.containername)
  name                  = element(var.containername, count.index)
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on            = [azurerm_storage_account.sa-int]

}

resource "null_resource" "log" {

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.container
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage logging update --log rwd --retention 30 --services qtb --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name} --account-key ${azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.primary_access_key}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {

  name                = ........
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnetwork.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rgnetwork.location
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id
  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = .........
    private_dns_zone_ids = [data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns.id]
  }
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = ........
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.log]
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "record" {

  provider            = azurerm.sub
  name                = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name
  zone_name           = data.azurerm_private_dns_zone.dns.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "nwrule" {

  storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.id
  default_action             = "Deny"
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.subnet.id]
  bypass                     = ["AzureServices"]
  depends_on                 = [azurerm_private_dns_a_record.record]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.kv.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.identity.0.principal_id

  key_permissions    = ["Get", "List"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get"]

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.sa-int]
}

please help me to resolve this error.
Error Screenshots -



The context deadline exceeded error usually occurred due to network issue and takes longer than the default timeout value.
In your case, you’re using azurerm version 3.0, which may also be causing the issue. It's recommended to upgrade to the latest version using the command below.

Note: In my case, I'm using the latest version, which executed successfully without any issues

terraform init -upgrade


provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  subscription_id = "8332bffjgjgjglhla507-d7e60e5f09a9"
}

data "azurerm_resource_group" "rg" {
  name = "Network-RG"
}
data "azurerm_client_config" "current" {
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_zone" "dnszone" {
  name                = "venkattest.com"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
}

data "azurerm_subnet" "demosubnet" {
  name                 = "demo-subnet"
  virtual_network_name = "demo-vnet"
  resource_group_name  = "Network-RG"
}

data "azurerm_key_vault" "keyvault" {
  name                = "demo-keyvaulttest"
  resource_group_name = "Network-RG"
}

variable "containername" {
  description = "List of container names to be created in the storage account"
  type        = list(string)
  default     = ["container1", "container2", "container3"]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa-int" {
  name                             = "demostortedhfnttest"
  resource_group_name              = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location                         = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  account_tier                     = "Standard"
  account_replication_type         = "LRS"
  allow_nested_items_to_be_public  = false
  cross_tenant_replication_enabled = false
  min_tls_version                  = "TLS1_2"
  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }
  timeouts {
    create = "1h"
    update = "30m"
    delete = "30m"
  }  
  blob_properties {
    delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }
    container_delete_retention_policy {
      days = 30
    }

  }
  queue_properties {
    logging {
      delete                = true
      read                  = true
      write                 = true
      version               = "1.0"
      retention_policy_days = 10
    }
    hour_metrics {
      enabled               = true
      include_apis          = true
      retention_policy_days = 10
      version               = "1.0"

    }
    minute_metrics {
      enabled               = true
      include_apis          = true
      retention_policy_days = 10
      version               = "1.0"


    }

  }
}

resource "azurerm_storage_container" "container" {
  count                 = length(var.containername)
  name                  = element(var.containername, count.index)
  storage_account_name  = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name
  container_access_type = "private"
  depends_on            = [azurerm_storage_account.sa-int]

}

resource "null_resource" "log" {

  triggers = {
    always_run = timestamp()
  }
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_storage_container.container
  ]
  provisioner "local-exec" {
    command = "az storage logging update --log rwd --retention 30 --services qtb --account-name ${azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name} --account-key ${azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.primary_access_key}"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_private_endpoint" "endpoint" {

  name                = "demostorageendpoint"
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.location
  subnet_id           = data.azurerm_subnet.demosubnet.id
  private_dns_zone_group {
    name                 = "demodns"
    private_dns_zone_ids = [azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnszone.id]
  }
  private_service_connection {
    name                           = "demoserviceconnection"
    is_manual_connection           = false
    private_connection_resource_id = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.id
    subresource_names              = ["blob"]
  }

  depends_on = [null_resource.log]
}

provider "azurerm" {
  alias    = "globalsub"
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_private_dns_a_record" "record" {

  #provider            = azurerm.sub
  name                = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.name
  zone_name           = azurerm_private_dns_zone.dnszone.name
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
  ttl                 = 10
  records             = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint.private_service_connection[0].private_ip_address]
  depends_on          = [azurerm_private_endpoint.endpoint]
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account_network_rules" "nwrule" {

  storage_account_id         = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.id
  default_action             = "Deny"
  virtual_network_subnet_ids = [data.azurerm_subnet.demosubnet.id]
  bypass                     = ["AzureServices"]
  depends_on                 = [azurerm_private_dns_a_record.record]
}

resource "azurerm_key_vault_access_policy" "storage" {
  key_vault_id = data.azurerm_key_vault.keyvault.id
  tenant_id    = data.azurerm_client_config.current.tenant_id
  object_id    = azurerm_storage_account.sa-int.identity.0.principal_id

  key_permissions    = ["Get", "List"]
  secret_permissions = ["Get"]

  depends_on = [azurerm_storage_account.sa-int]
}


Note: As per your code, the private endpoint is attached to the storage account, granting default access to the storage account from the VNet used in the private endpoint. Therefore, it's unnecessary to add the same VNet again in the firewall section.


If you still want to attach the VNet in the firewall section, ensure that the Microsoft.Storage service endpoint is enabled for the subnet you are using


After executing the code, all the resource has been created successfully without any error.



Received below error ---
31mError:1mretrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: "***"
Resource Group Name: "rg-name"
Storage Account Name: "sa-name"): executing request: Get "https://sa-name.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=service": dial tcp: lookup sa-name.blob.core.windows.net: no such host[0m

Looks like you are hardcoding the blob endpoint URL in your code and saying no such endpoint available . You can try my code, which will get the storage account details from the code instead of hardcoding.

I have used your code and I have not hardcoded the endpoint URL. But still same error

Can you please share the terraform apply error screenshot.

I have added the screenshot of the tf apply in the description. Please help.
Error: [0m[0m[1mretrieving static website properties for Storage Account (Subscription: "***"
2024-11-04T03:33:56.7897718Z [31m│[0m [0mResource Group Name: "rg-name"
Storage Account Name: "sa-int"): executing request: Get "https://sa-int-name.blob.core.windows.net/?comp=properties&restype=service": dial tcp: lookup sa-int-name.blob.core.windows.net: no such host
with azurerm_storage_account.sa-int,
on main.tf line 23, in resource "azurerm_storage_account" "sa-int":
resource "azurerm_storage_account"

The above error was encountered in the storage module. If possible, please delete the current directory and try again with a new directory. Confirm once done.
